# Exiting 'Print Layout' when viewing a read-only Google Doc

Tags: google-docs

I'm creating some instructional material and sharing it with coworkers via Google Docs. I have Ownership and Edit rights on these documents while my co-workers have Read access.

The document is properly formatted when I view my work in Edit mode. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

But when my readers view this same document, they get this retro page-style view, like something from 90's era Microsoft Word. Notice the gap and physical page breaks, as though the document were going to be sent to a physical printer:

[image]

After a bit of research I discovered that the printer-style view can be turned on and off using the Print Layout toggle:

[image]

...but for reasons I don't quite understand, when the document is viewed by my coworkers in Read mode, that retro style Print Layout becomes the default and the option to turn it off is removed:

[image]

So everyone other than the editor who views this document is forced to do so using this ridiculous printer-centric layout. Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

In your non-"print mode" document, there appears to be a page break above the image (the light gray line). Perhaps that is the cause of at least some of your problems.